# loop through div continuously w/ auto scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a page loads with the div below I want the page to start auto scrolling and keep looping through the content over and over again. To see an example of what I am trying to achieve go [here](https://taggbox.com/w/globalwarming)

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div class="post">some content</div>
    <div class="post">some content</div>
    <div class="post">some content</div>
    <div class="post">some content</div>
    <div class="post">some content</div>
    <div class="post">some content</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have tried almost everything with no success.

Comment: That's going to be an annoying experience for many users.

Comment: I agree entirely with Vohuman, that is going to become crazy annoying.

Comment: We have no context for the OP's question. This could be some kind of "demo" feature, or a background effect for an onboarding page. There are plenty of situations where the effect would be appropriate (and cool!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the scroll position of an element by setting the `scrollTop` property. To update it continuously, you could try:

```
var scrollDistancePerSecond = 50; // Scroll 50px every second.
var scrollDistancePerAnimationFrame = Math.ceil(scrollDistancePerSecond  / 60); // Animate at 60 fps.
var wrapper = document.getElementById('contentwrapper');

autoScroll(wrapper);
function autoScroll(element){
    if (element.scrollTop < element.scrollHeight)
      window.requestAnimationFrame(autoScroll.bind(null,element));
    element.scrollTop += scrollDistancePerAnimationFrame;
}
```

Live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1ue918v/3/).

As for the continuous loop, you could wrap the `.post` elements in an inner wrapper (e.g., a `<div id="inner-wrap">`. Then you could duplicate the content by appending a clone of the inner-wrapped elements inside the outer wrapper.

```
var innerWrap = document.getElementById('inner-wrap');
var clone = document.createElement('div');
clone.innerHTML = innerWrap.innerHTML;
wrapper.append(clone);
```

Then, inside your animation function, you can check whether the wrapper's `scrollTop` has reached `innerWrap.scrollHeight`. If it has, you can jump back to the top! It'll take some fine-tuning to get a seamless effect.

### Update

The linked page does not use scrollTop, but animates the `y` component of the CSS transform `translate3d` on the wrapper `<div>`. You might get more performant results using CSS `transition`s or `animation`s over JavaScript. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1ue918v/5/) is an example in pure CSS3.

Comment: I am trying not to use clone, I would prefer it just set the div position to appear to be scrolling non stop. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user45612318 I'd be interested to learn of a solution like that myself! I don't think it's possible to avoid a clone if you want a seamless animation. If you watch the page that you linked, you'll notice that when it's scrolled all the way to the bottom, it just skips back to the top! There is no clone used, and it is definitely not seamless. The answer I posted, minus the clone, would look similar.

Comment: I found a solution with clone, however, I am struggling with the auto scroll function, maybe you could take a look and help? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfs52xu9/)

Comment: Your solution is very smooth! [Here's that exact same fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfs52xu9/1/), merged with the fiddle I linked in my answer's **Update** section. Notice that I've animated the `translate3d` property to a `y` coordinate of 75%, since the overlap of cloned elements makes the remaining 25%. Oh, you also forgot to call `requestAnimationFrame` in the `reCalc` function— it has to be recursive or it won't form a loop!

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!